# Asynchronous call in google appengine using task queues in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

Im new to task queue api in google app engine. I have created a new queue and added a task in it using the taskqueue.add() function. I have defined the url of the task and have written down the logic for the task the url. But the task is NOT HAPPENING ASYNCHRONOUSLY as the app is waiting for the task to complete and then it continues executing the statement after the taskqueue.add() function. How do i make the task asynchronous? Any help on this issue is appreciated.

the code looks like this

```
class botinitiate(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # some more statements here
        template_values = {'token': token,
                           'me': user.user_id()
                          }

        taskqueue.add(url='/autobot', params={'key':game_key},queue_name='autobot')
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))


class autobot(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        # task logic goes here


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/botinitiate',botinitiate),('/autobot',autobot)],debug=True)


def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks

Comment: How did you confirm that the app is *waiting* for the task to complete to send a response?

Comment: by using the logs of the appengine. It finishes the task before it continues with the statements after the taskqueue.add()

Comment: Sample code from both the handler initiating the task and the task itself would be helpful.

Comment: i have added the code in the message

Answer (score 2):

The recently developed [dev_appserver2](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/) provides concurrency between user requests and task queue requests, for a more accurate emulation of production.

Answer (score 0):

Task queues on App Engine are asynchronous; there's no way for the request that enqueued the task to know when the task is run (short of making RPC calls or other deliberate communication). What you may be observing is the single-threaded nature of the dev_appserver development environment; this certainly won't be the case in production.

Answer (score 0):

So you'd use:

```
add_async(task, transactional=False, rpc=None)
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/queues

You'd need to read the docs at the above URL and apply it to your own code.